# Asp.Net Core 2 Authorization

Tags: c#, authorization, jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

Some background information: I have managed to create a working web API which utilizes Azure AD as well as JWT (username & password - database) with regards to authorization.

To test the API, I just open the browser window, execute the action - on the client controller: http://localhost:5000/api/client (which has the `Authorize` attribute on it) and Azure AD auth takes over. Once authenticated, the return Uri completes the action and return client data.

Since the `DefaultChallengeScheme` is set to `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, I'm guessing that's why Azure AD is being used when I perform the test mentioned above. There is not explicit controller/action in the API that states, *hey use this to auth against azure ad* - instead everything is setup in `ConfigureServices` [`Startup.cs`]

Is there a way I can allow the user to make use of a controller/action to auth against Azure AD, as I'm doing with my JWT (username/password)

I'm more than willing to provide code snippets - just wanted to avoid a code dump

Comment: do you mean you ONLY want to user to login from Azure AD and remove the choice?

Comment: No, when the user wants to login with their user name & password, I just call the token action on the API (which uses JWT). In other words I have an entry point for that. Now when the user wants to utilize Azure, where is my entry point. Currently, the default challenge scheme is OpenId, so Azure takes over. And this is the thing, how can I manage this, without hard-coding it

Comment: How about tracking the request when users choose the Azure AD option for authentication? Please feel free to let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: @FeiXue - I'll update my question. I think I should ask my question differently

Comment: Still not able to understand the issue exactly. I assume that you config multiple authentication middle ware for the project and you want to specify the  data provider explicitly. For example, [here](https://github.com/VitorX/webappLocalAccountAAD) is a demo project which integrate with local accounts and Azure Active Directory. The frond-end is using `post` request to choose the identity data provider like the request `post: /Account/ExternalLogin` with form data(`provider:OpenIdConnect`).

Comment: So that the server will redirect to the identity data provider by the settings on the server for this specific data provider.  Then if we want to login with the specific data provider directly, we can using request generate by the authentication middle-ware like the authorization request `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F&state=12345`.

Comment: The exact request that for your project, you can  track it using the Chrome.

Comment: @FeiXue oh boy, ok thanks, I'll check it out ... soz - this is my project: https://github.com/Programm3r/Ystervark